# Verify object deletion in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, garbage-collection

In my code there are many objects created and deleted during runtime which can have long reference chains (i.e. be reachable in terms of garbage collection from many places).

In my unit test I want to verify that when I "delete" an object, e.g. remove it from the list that primarily contains it, all references to that object are deleted. To be clear: I want to verify that no reference to this object exists anymore in my application.

How can I achieve this?

So far I came only up with this (testing that a [PhantomReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) is enqueued):

```
@Test
public void test_objectX_can_be_garbage_collected() throws Exception {

    ReferenceQueue<MyClass> refsToBeDeleted = new ReferenceQueue<>();
    MyClass obj = new MyClass();
    PhantomReference<MyClass> phantomRef = new PhantomReference<MyClass>(obj, refsToBeDeleted);

    obj = null;   // delete last strong reference to obj
    System.out.println("Reference is enqueued:" + phantomRef.isEnqueued()); // "false"

    System.gc();   // invoke garbage collection
    Thread.sleep(1000L);   // required - see text
    System.gc();   // invoke garbage collection again
    System.out.println("Reference is enqueued:" + phantomRef.isEnqueued()); // true
}
```

with

```
public static class MyClass {
}
```

The [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc--) says:

> public static void gc()
>
> Runs the garbage collector.
>   Calling the gc method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory they currently occupy available for quick reuse. **When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort to reclaim space from all discarded objects.**

(emphasis mine)

This is quite vague ("best effort") and seems quite non-deterministic, e.g. I have to either wait 1 second and call `gc()` again, or call it e.g. four times in a row for the reference to be enqueued.

Is there any way to do this properly? I want to test that objects don't persist and will eventually flood my memory after months of uptime.

Remarks:

1.) I know you should not call `gc()` because it's bad code. True, but I am calling it from test code to verify production code.

2.) I know that `gc()` is actually not deterministic from a local point of view. I'm aware of this and asking for a better alternative.

**Edit:**

I realized that this *can* be a kind of "special" unit test: If it succeeds once for a given code base, I know that this reference is garbage collected; if the unit test fails it might be because `gc()` didn't want to delete it, or it could not be deleted. So this test *can* verify that the memory is released, but it might need several attempts for that verification. However, this is "special" (read: "bad") because I would have to accept a randomly failing unit test.

Comment: Would it be easier to use a Java memory analyser?

Comment: @SteveSmith might be the case - I have to admit I never used one... However I want to automatically test this.

Comment: A random *dangerous and hacky* thought: launch a new VM with a relative small heap. In this VM create your objects, then delete the desired ones, then create an infinte linked list to consume heap until a OutOfMemoryError is thrown, thus ensuring a gc is performed. Check if the reference is cleared now. If cleared, test pass. If not, test failed. This will be deterministic but can be very very hard to create and maintain. I'm not sure how VM behaves after an OutOfMemoryError, thus the idea may not work at all. It is yours to decide whether or not to pay effort and time on my silly advice.

Comment: IMHO you *can* rely on `System.gc` in the test. It's *not random*, it works always, unless turned off. It won't get turned off as long nobody does it. So don't do it and guard your computed well. :D

Comment: @maaartinus Thanks, but I don't understand why I have to call System.gc() _several times_ (either with a sleep in between, or three to four times, on my machine) to successfully enqueue that reference. How do I know how often is "correct"? This is not how it's specified in the docs ("when gc returns, it has done a best-effort..."), because if the best-effort succeeds after three consecutive calls, the first call was not best-effort imho.

Comment: @user2055010 Then I'm afraid, I was wrong - it's a long time I tested it the last time (I guess, the problem is not the GC, but the enqueuing). Still, calling it in a loop (with a timeout) until you see that it worked should be good enough for a test. The worst outcome possible is your test taking too long or even hitting the timeout. A failing test is pretty bad, but when the probability is so low that it actually never happens, it should be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to make sure that an object has been garbage collected. Calling `System.gc()` will usually result in garbage collection, but not always.

I also have a infinitely running Java process - I call `System.gc()` at the beginning of each iteration and record the resulting amount of used memory. If this amount does not significantly change over time, I can be reasonably sure not to "leak" memory.

Answer (score 0):

I've observed that when a heap dump is triggered, it usually does a full GC. If that is a policy of JVM to force GC during a Heap collection, then you can trigger a heap collection by

```
kill -3 pid
```

and see if it works.

> You might need to add jvm arguments for getting a heap dump.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a problem using reference and `System.gc()` for testing (though I prefer weak references instead phantom ones). I do not remember any stability problems for such approach.

Reference based approach work only if you can get reference to object which may be leaked.

I have [forked version](https://github.com/aragozin/jvm-tools/tree/master/hprof-heap) of head dump analysis library from NetBeans, which I use to automate certain types of memory usage reports.

It is possible, for test code, to take heap dump of itself and inspect this dump assert specific number of objects of given type to be present.

[Here](https://github.com/aragozin/jvm-tools/blob/master/hprof-heap/src/test/java/org/netbeans/lib/profiler/heap/BaseHeapTest.java) you can find example of such approach.

Comment: Sounds very interesting. I have never worked with NetBeans heap analyzer; do you know if an objects which is not reachable still exists "on the heap" (i.e. would be returned by `heap.getAllInstances()` (in the example) while it is not garbage collected)?

Comment: It depends. Heap dump command can either dump heap as is or full GC and dump. In test, I'm using second option. Though API allow dumping uncollected heap too.

Comment: System.gc() is not guaranteed to do anything. There is nothing stopping the JVM vendor from implementing it as a nop. Also, you can't rely on it garbage collecting every time (or even know if it's full or partial GC you are going to get), so never ever use System.gc in a deterministic test.